# What does the globe icon next to the "Questions" link mean?

Tags: support, design, icons, left-nav

There is a globe icon next to the "Questions" link on the left menu on each SE site:

> [image: Globe]

What's the meaning of that icon?

If this is about public (around the world) part of the site, why is the icon not placed next to "PUBLIC" word? Other links ("Tags", "Users", and "Unanswered") refer to public parts as well.